# One of the item in the checklist has an adjacent textbox

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Hope someone could teach me how to do this html/asp.net. Below is my expected output:

[image]

There is a line for the question. Then below is a checlist on two columns and the last item has a textbox beside it.

Sorry, I'm not good in UI. If someone could possibly direct me how to achieve this. Thank you!

```
<Table runat="server" ID="tblQuestionnaire3b">
        <tr>
            <td Style="padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:40px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px;">
                <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkAnswer7" RepeatColumns="2" CssClass="rblSpace">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="[Compound bow]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="[Recurve bow]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="[Crossbow]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="[Shotgun]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="[In-line muzzleloader]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="[Primitive muzzleloader]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="[Rifle (please enter caliber:22, 30, etc.)]">                           
                    </asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAnswer7" CssClass="txtboxSpace" width="80pt" />                   
            </td>                 
        </tr>
    </Table>
```

Comment: There are several dozens of ways to do this. The correct one depends on context from the rest of the system.

Comment: I just posted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would dump the use of some table for layout.

However, moving the text box out of the table, and a simple "br" to start the next line would also work.

However, the easiest way to lay things out?

Use what I call the kindergarten blocks idea.

So, each div is a block. Do you want the block to be floated to the left of existing content, or start a new line?

So, say these 2 div:

So, you just start dropping these "blocks" into the form.

So, this:

```
        <div id="block1" style="float:left;background-color:lightcoral;float:left">
            <h3>this is my block 1</h3>
            <p>This is some fun text</p>
        </div>


        <div id="block2" style="float:left;background-color:lightblue;float:left">
            <h3>this is my block 2</h3>
            <p>This is some fun text</p>
        </div>
```

Result:

[image]

Say, I want some space, so then this for 2nd block:

```
        <div id="block2" style="float:left;background-color:lightblue;float:left;margin-left:30px">
            <h3>this is my block 2</h3>
            <p>This is some fun text</p>
        </div>
```

So, I bumped it over 30px. Thus:

[image]

And it makes your page "responsive" without all kinds of hand stands.

And, want the 2nd block to start on a new/next line?

then drop in a div between the 2 blocks like this:

```
        <div id="block1" style="float:left;background-color:lightcoral;float:left">
            <h3>this is my block 1</h3>
            <p>This is some fun text</p>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>


        <div id="block2" style="float:left;background-color:lightblue;float:left">
            <h3>this is my block 2</h3>
            <p>This is some fun text</p>
        </div>
```

Thus:

[image]

And add some space between the blocks?

```
        <div style="clear:both;height:20px"></div>
```

And now:

[image]

So, with this VERY simple concept of thinking of your "div" as a kindergarten block? Then you just start tossing blocks on the web page.

Float them left, and they will go across the page.

Want to start a new line, then drop in that div clear both.

So, with the above most simple approach to web design in the history of man kind?

And super easy and super simple?

Then we just drop your first check box list into a div, and then start some more content below based on the clear both trick.
Hence, your markup becomes this:

```
        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkAnswer7" RepeatColumns="2" CssClass="rblSpace">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="[Compound bow]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="[Recurve bow]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="[Crossbow]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="[Shotgun]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="[In-line muzzleloader]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="[Primitive muzzleloader]"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="[Rifle (please enter caliber:22, 30, etc.)]">                           
                    </asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both;height:10pt"></div>

        <div style="float:left">

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAnswer7"  width="80pt" />                   

        </div>
```

And thus:

[image]

But here is the really cool part. Say you change your mind, and you want the text box and some other content to the right of the check box list?

Then remove the clear both, and add some margin-left

Say this:

```
    <div style="float:left">
        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkAnswer7" RepeatColumns="2" CssClass="rblSpace">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="[Compound bow]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="[Recurve bow]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="[Crossbow]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="[Shotgun]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="[In-line muzzleloader]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="[Primitive muzzleloader]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="[Rifle (please enter caliber:22, 30, etc.)]">                           
                </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>


    <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;border-color:black;border:solid;padding:10px">
        <h4>Some fun content to the right</h4>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAnswer7"  width="80pt" />                   
    </div>
```

And thus, you get this:

[image]

So, just start dropping "divs", and keep floating them. If your browser is reduced, note how the floated div’s cascade down below.

So, with the above simple div block approach, then you can quite much freely build any layout you want, and no need for messy bootstrap columns, no need for some table for layout either.

In fact, grab some child blocks, put them on your desk, and use them to layout things. Drop a block. Now, is the next block to the right, or down below.

So, now, your layout becomes child's play, and you only need to know about float:left, and clear both.

As noted, with above, I been able to create quite much any web page I ever wanted.

And maybe on that 2nd line, you want the text box on the right side?

Then float the text box to the right, and hence this:

```
    <div style="float:left">
        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkAnswer7" RepeatColumns="2" CssClass="rblSpace">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="[Compound bow]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="[Recurve bow]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="[Crossbow]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="[Shotgun]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="[In-line muzzleloader]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="[Primitive muzzleloader]"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="[Rifle (please enter caliber:22, 30, etc.)]">                           
                </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>

            <div style="float:right;margin-top:-20px">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAnswer7" 
                         />
            </div>
    </div>
```

And you now have this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is very thorough. This helps me understand how the blocking works for UI.